# Adding form elements via ajax; input not stored in $form_state['values']

Tags: 7, ajax

I am trying to add a date, start time, end time to a form - the user can add as many 'rows' as necessary.  The form fields are being added to the form correctly, and the $form_state['input'] is showing the correct values that were input on the form. However, the $form_state['values'] is only showing the last one, e.g. if I add three (bringing the total to 4) it only includes the last value.

Relevant code in the form builder:

```
$num_dates = !isset($form_state['num_dates']) ? 1 : $form_state['num_dates'];
$form_state['num_dates'] = $num_dates;
$form['date']['#prefix'] = '<div id="form-date-wrapper">';
$form['date']['#suffix'] = '</div><!-- /#form-date-wrapper -->';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_dates; $i ++)
{
  $form['date']['calendar_date' . $num_dates] = array(
    '#title' => 'Date',
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#maxlength' => 15,
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('calendar-date')),
      '#prefix' => '<div class="form-date-entry-wrapper form-row form-row-single-item">',
  );
  $form['date']['event_start_time' . $num_dates] = array(
  '#title' => 'Start Time',
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('9:00 AM'), t('9:15 AM'))),
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('calendar-date-times')),
  );
  $form['date']['event_end_time' . $num_dates] = array(
  '#title' => 'End Time',
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('9:00 AM'), t('9:15 AM'))),
      '#suffix' => '</div> <!-- /form-date-entry-wrapper -->',
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('calendar-date-times')),
  );
}
$form['add_another_date_time'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
    '#title' => 'Add Another Date/Time',
    '#value' => 'Add Another Date/Time',
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('look-like-text-button')),
    '#submit' => array('exhibitorevents_form_add_date_time_submit'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'exhibitorevents_form_add_date_time',
        'wrapper' => 'form-date-wrapper',
        'method' => 'append',
        'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
);
    $form['submit'] = array(
  '#title' => 'Submit',
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'submit',
  '#weight' => 100,
);
```

And the callback functions:

```
/**
 * Ajax callback for add more dates/times
 */
function exhibitorevents_form_add_date_time($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['date'];
}
/**
 * Submit handler for add more dates/times button
 * 
 * Increments num_dates +1
 */
 function exhibitorevents_form_add_date_time_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   $form_state['num_dates']++;  
   $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
 }
```

I have added the $form_state['input'] & $form_state['values'] array here: http://pastebin.com/nL3DWHm8 for reference.  This particular example, I added one date 'row', making 2 total.

Comment: where are you trying to get the value. could you show the that function as well.

Comment: As of now, for testing, I'm just dumping the $form_state on form submission:
    
    `function giveaway_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
 _dvd($form_state);
    ...
    }`

Comment: `_dvd()` is just a convenience wrapper I use for debugging, btw

Comment: and you have another button that you click to get it

Comment: @MohammedShameem, yes.  It is just a default submit button which calls the default submit handler ({form-name}_submit), in this case `giveaway_form_submit`.  I have added it to the form builder code in the questions.  Thanks!

Comment: have you added $form['#tree'] = TRUE; ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7188/discussion-between-mohammed-shameem-and-clrockwell)

Comment: @MohammedShameem. So, it was four part: 1) Add in $form['#tree'] = TRUE; 2) refactor my for loop 3) use 'replace' instead of 'append' as the ['#ajax']['method'] 4) pass $form_state as reference (this was only necessary because I have the function which puts together common form elements).  I also took your suggestions from our chat to clean up the code a bit.  Your comment suggesting the $form['#tree'] should be turned into an answer, then I'll comment and accept.  The new loop: http://pastebin.com/P8MYnMMH and the resulting $form_state['values']: http://pastebin.com/fHx4xvN3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the $form['#tree'] so that all the values are passed.